# Is it coincidence that “плуг” in Russian is so similar to “plough” in English (they mean the same thing)

Tags: этимология

The translation of “plough”, a farming tool, into Russian is «плуг», they sound very similar, why? What’s the etymology of these words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Этимологический словарь Фасмера](https://lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3) утверждает, что *"плуг"* заимствовано из древне-верхне-немецкого:

> род. п. -а, укр. плуг, др.-русск. плугъ (Пов. врем. лет под 981 г.),
> сербск.-цслав. плугъ, болг. плуг, сербохорв. плу̏г, словен. plùg,
> род. п. plúga, чеш. pluh, plouh, слвц. pluh, польск. pług, в.-луж.
> płuh, н.-луж. pług, полаб. pläug **Заимств. из д.-в.-н. pfluog «плуг»**,
> др.-исл. plógr, англос. plóg, которые сближают частью с нов.-в.-н.
> рflеgеn «ухаживать», частью — с нов.-в.-н. Рflосk «колышек» (Мерингер,
> IF 16, 184 и сл.; 17, 100 и сл.; 18, 244 и сл.; Уленбек, AfslPh 15,
> 490; РВВ 35, 176 и сл.; Торп 222; Ван-Вейк, IF 23, 366 и сл.; 28, 125
> и сл.; Мейе, ét. 179; Стендер-Петерсен 407 и сл.; Сергиевский, ИРЯ 2,
> 357 и сл.) Недоказуемо кельт.-ретийское происхождение герм. слова,
> потому что слово plaumoratum «колесный плуг» у Плиния (Nat. hist. 18,
> 172) не получило надежного объяснения; см. Вальде-Гофм. 2, 319 и сл.;
> М.-Любке 549; против см. Янко, WuS 1, 106 и сл.; Гуйер, LF 36, 59 и
> сл. Абсолютно невероятно также ввиду широкого распространения герм.
> слов заимствование их из слав., вопреки Брюкнеру (AfslPh 23, 626),
> Террасу (ZfslPh 19, 123); ср. Кипарский 258 и сл. и Брюкнер, AfslPh
> 42, 142; Słown. 422 [Попытку исконнослав. этимологии *plugъ из *рlеu-,
> *рlоu- «течь, лить(ся), тащить» см. у Мошинского (JР, 36, 1956, стр. 1 и сл.); см. еще подробно Мартынов, Труды Одесск. унив., 148, 1958,
> стр. 166 и сл. — Т.]

Английское *"plough"* также имеет германское происхождение:
[image]

Так что эти слова имеют общее происхождение.